# Record linkage using String similarity Techniques

Tags: string, record, similarity, levenshtein-distance, linkage

We are working on Record linkage project.
We are observing a strange behavior from all of the standard technique like Jaro Winkler, Levenshtein, N-Gram, Damerau-Levenshtein, Jaccard index, Sorensen-Dice

Say,
String 1= MINI GRINDER KIT
String 2= Weiler 13001 Mini Grinder Accessory Kit, For Use With Small Right Angle Grinders
String 3= Milwaukee Video Borescope, Rotating Inspection Scope, Series: M-SPECTOR 360, 2.7 in 640 x 480 pixels High-Resolution LCD, Plastic, Black/Red

In the above case string 1 and string 2 are related the score of all the methods as shown below.
Jaro Winkler -> 0.391666651
Levenshtein  -> 75
N-Gram,     -> 0.9375
Damerau -> 75
Jaccard index -> 0
Sorensen-Dice -> 0
Cosine -> 0

But string 1 and string 3 are not at all related, but distance method are giving very high score.
Jaro Winkler -> 0.435714275
Levenshtein  -> 133
N-Gram,     -> 0.953571439
Damerau -> 133
Jaccard index -> 1
Sorensen-Dice -> 0
Cosine -> 0

Any thoughts .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All distance calculation score are case sensitive. Hence bring all of them to same case. Then you get to see the score calculation appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your goal here is to check if the two products are same or not. The data are form different sources i guess, in case of data like this you'll need to find out what is the most important mention worth comparing?! The brand name, the specs, etc...

These metrics follow very crude notion of similarity!, don't just feed the data like that.

So first Clean(remove punctuation, non important words), tokenize(break it single word sentences) then maybe u can use [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) to help find a better match.